# Should cpu memory bandwidth match with video memory bandwidth?

Tags: memory, cpu, gpu, bandwidth

I found somewhere that the video memory bandwidth is a good indicator of performance on video cards. I checked a few examples and it correlates pretty well with benchmark points.

I read in another text that the GPU can use only the video memory, and the CPU should copy the content of the RAM to video memory if it wants the GPU to compute something for it.

Does this copy happen very often? Does this mean that the memory bandwidth of the CPU should somehow match with the bandwidth of the video card, otherwise the CPU will limit the GPU performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relatively easy supposition to test.  There are 3 figures to look at:

1. CPU to memory bandwidth
2. PCIe bandwidth (CPU to GPU)
3. GPU bandwidth

CPU bandwidth figures can be found on the manufacturer website, PCIe x16 bandwidth is a known figure and GPU manufacturers also publish those figures.

So for a high end [i7-8700](https://ark.intel.com/products/126686/Intel-Core-i7-8700-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-4_60-GHz) with an x16 [PCIe](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express?wprov=sfla1) 3.0 link and an [Nvidia 1080](https://www.nvidia.co.uk/geforce/products/10series/geforce-gtx-1080/) the figures are as follows

1. 48GB/s (CPU to memory)
2. ~16GB/s (PCIe bandwidth (CPU to GPU))
3. 320GB/s (GPU bandwidth)

So while the CPU has relatively good bandwidth to its local memory and the GPU has a massive link to its memory it would appear that the link between the two devices is limited.

For games this is not really a problem, a game simply loads up the GPU with texture and scene data and after that the bandwidth requirements are relatively small.

For GPGPU tasks it depends entirely on your data as to whether the limited bandwidth link between CPU and GPU is a problem.

The answer is that it depends on what you are doing with the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of video cards that are distinct by their usage of memory.

**Integrated**

An integrated GPU doesn't use its own RAM; it utilizes the system's memory instead.
Its main advantage is, frankly, that it is cheap.
Integrated graphics cards are low-end, so when playing 3D games you may need to turn down the graphics settings.

**Dedicated**

A dedicated, or discrete, GPU has its own independent source of video memory, leaving the RAM your system uses untouched. That memory is completely separate from your computer's system memory. Dedicated cards are for serious gaming or professional graphic designer.

**Conclusion**

For an integrated GPU, there is only one memory, so no copies are required.
For a dedicated GPU, there is no connection between the two memories, so bandwidths
do not need to match, and there are still no copies.